# determine all abelian groups of order $n = p^3q^2$ up to isomorphism , where $p$ and $q$ are distinct prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I'm not too sure how to do this but the only thing i learned to solve this would be the fundamental theorem of finite abelian group. So my reasoning would be $p^3q^2$ can be written in these following manner: $p^3q^2, p^3qq,p^2pq^2,p^2pqq,pppq^2,pppqq$. so in total there would be 6 different groups of order $n = p^3q^2$ up to isomorphism. the following groups would be :

$\mathbb{Z}_{p^3} \times \mathbb{Z}_{q^2}$

$\mathbb{Z}_{p^3} \times \mathbb{Z}_{q} \times \mathbb{Z}_{q}$

$\mathbb{Z}_{p^2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{p} \times \mathbb{Z}_{q^2}$

$\mathbb{Z}_{p^2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{p} \times \mathbb{Z}_{q} \times \mathbb{Z}_{q}$

$\mathbb{Z}_{p} \times \mathbb{Z}_{p} \times \mathbb{Z}_{p} \times \mathbb{Z}_{q^2}$

$\mathbb{Z}_{p} \times \mathbb{Z}_{p} \times \mathbb{Z}_{p} \times \mathbb{Z}_{q}\times \mathbb{Z}_{q}$

Is this how I should proceed to find all abelian groups of this order. I'm just confused since I only did problems of this sort with real numbers so I wasn't sure if it would be the same steps with variables. and also would it be the same step if p and q weren't prime.

Comment: Yes, assume your $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian groups is all you need. If $p$ and $q$ are not primes, you would have to use a different approach as you do not know their prime factorisations.